# Tensorflow: variable batch_size gives error when trying to predict with eval (Dimensions of inputs should match)

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow-serving

I am training a model with variable batch_size (first batches are 200). So I have used batch_size None to make it variable (I couldn't do that for init_state because it gave an error).

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, num_steps], name='input_placeholder')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, num_steps], name='labels_placeholder')
init_state = tf.zeros([batch_size, state_size])
rnn_inputs = tf.one_hot(x, num_classes)

with tf.variable_scope('softmax'):
    W = tf.get_variable('W', [state_size, num_classes])
    b = tf.get_variable('b', [num_classes], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
logits = tf.reshape(
            tf.matmul(tf.reshape(rnn_outputs, [-1, state_size]), W) + b,
            [batch_size, num_steps, num_classes])
predictions = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```

Training the model goes well.

Then I try to predict probabilities with an x of shape (1, 10) instead of (200, 10):

I tried:

```
test = np.array([[1, 2 , 3 , 4, 5, 6 ,7, 8, 9 ,10]], dtype=np.int32)
  print (predictions.eval(feed_dict = {x:test}))
```

I also tried in a sligly different way with:

```
preds, state = sess.run([g['preds'],g['final_state']], feed_dict)
```

Same error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [1,1058] vs. shape[1] = [200,4]
     [[Node: rnn/while/basic_rnn_cell/basic_rnn_cell/concat = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](rnn/while/TensorArrayReadV3, rnn/while/Identity_2, rnn/while/basic_rnn_cell/basic_rnn_cell/concat/axis)]]
```

So 1058 is my num_classes, 200 is the (initial) batch_size and 4 is the width of the tensor.

I think I am not using the variable batch_size correctly. Any ideas on what to change?

Comment: Can you use `batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0]` to get the fed batch size as a Tensor, then use that in the remainder of the model? It looks like that should work for the uses in the snippet above.

Comment: The problem is, if I define this batch_size before x, it doesn't know x yet. If I define it after x, then it doesn't know the batch_size yet... so where to put this? I suppose I can keep batch_size to None when defining x.. .Trying now...

Comment: Ok that worked. Do you want to post it as an answer?